# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer resnet50: expected shape=(None, 180, 180, 3), found shape=(180, 180, 3)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

With TFF 0.18, I found this problem :

```py
images, labels = next(img_gen.flow_from_directory(path0,target_size=(180, 180), batch_size = 2,class_mode=None))
sample_batch = (images,labels)  # assumes images and labels are np.ndarray
input_spec = tf.nest.map_structure(tensor_spec_from_ndarray, sample_batch)
```

here is the output of input_spec

```py
(TensorSpec(shape=(180, 180, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(180, 180, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```

And here is my model:

```py
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_tensor=tf.keras.Input(shape=(180, 180, 3)), pooling=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, the error message is saying the tensors are not the same rank (4 vs 3).

> `expected shape=(None, 180, 180, 3)`

The expected shape has a leading `None` dimension, which is the batch dimension.

> `found shape=(180, 180, 3)`

The found shape only has rank 3, with no batch dimension.

This is somewhat surprising from the code in the question which has the line `batch_size = 2`. I would dig into how that parameter is used by the `img_gen.flow_from_directory()` function to see if getting a batch dimension is possible.